# magento success page variables

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I am trying to capture some magento success page variables to pass to our advertising company.

So far I have got this but the variables are not outputting anything:

```
<?php 
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $price="'".$item->getPrice()."', ";
    $qty="'".$item->getQty()."', ";
    $sku="'".$item->getSku()."', ";
}
?>
```

The data needs to be in the format:

```
'price1', 'price2', 'price3'
'qty1', 'qty2', 'qty3'
'sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to Success.phtml

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();

$price = $qty = $sku = array();
foreach($items as $item){
  $price[] = $item->getPrice(); 
  $qty[] = $item->getQty();
  $sku[] = $item->getSku();
}

echo "'" . implode("', '", $price) . "'";
echo "'" . implode("', '", $qty) . "'";
echo "'" . implode("', '", $sku) . "'";
```

Comment: Hi RS, That is working great when using getQtyToInvoice instead of get Qty. Many thanks for your help. I am still learning PHP and it is great to learn where I have gone wrong.Is there any way to get the Configurable SKU instead of the Simple SKU?

Comment: You would need to get the simple product parent (which is the configurable) then get the sku ... take a look @ http://gabrielsomoza.com/magento/getting-a-products-parent-id-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

On your success.phtml page, you can do it:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId()); // follow the RS tip.
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach($items as $item){
    $price = $item->getData('price'); 
    $qty = $item->getData('qty');
    $sku = $item->getData('sku');
}
```

Gl

Comment: Hi GI, Unfortunately that is not generating anything for me (after changing $itens to $items). I am getting no errors but <?php echo $price ?> is not doing anything?