# How to add my template of thankyou page in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a custom shipping module for Magento but I am not able to get the order id in Thank you page of Magento as I have to send that order id to shipping provider.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the order id in your custom shipping module or after they place an order in success.phtml? How will you send the shipping provider the order id through an php (curl/soap/REST..) or javascript?

Comment: No i added the custom shipping module and it is working fine but i want to send order id to the shipping provider using curl on thank you page but not able to figure out. How.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the order id on the thank you page/Success.phtml

```
$this->getOrderId();
```

See [magento success page variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229965/magento-success-page-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Observer event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`. Create a class and a method. In this method you can get the variables, here is a sample:

```
class MyClass {
    public function MyMethod (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        // Array of order ids
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    }
}
```

If you need more details, take a look into the class `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController` and the method `successAction`